# Probability of holding two balls at the same time

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Imagine having five persons around a round table. Two consecutive person hold in their hand a ball. Each turn, a person gives the ball to one of its neighbour. How many turns should you wait so that one person holds the two balls at the same time ?

For the moment, I've made some effort studying the distance between the two balls $d_k$ which takes value within $0, 1, 2, 3$. Initially, $d_1 = 1$. I'm interested in the mean value of $k$ such that $d_k = 0$. What I have observed is :

-> if $d_k = 1$ then, the next turn, $d_{k+1} = 1$ with probability $3/4$ and $d_{k+1} = 2$ otherwise.\

-> if $d_k = 2$ then, the next turn, $d_{k+1} = 2$ with probability $1/2$, $d_{k+1} = 0$ with probability $1/4$ and $d_{k+1} = 3$ with probability $1/4$.\

But I don't succed in finding the law of $d_k$, any help ?

Comment: I'd do it with states.  We don't care who has the balls at any given moment, we only care about the distance between them, hence you get one state for each possible distance $\{0,1,2\}$.  Since distance $0$ is the end state, you only have two active states to consider.

Comment: Note:  you can't have distance $3$, given that we define the distance to be the *minimal* separation.  If the people are $A,B,C,D,E$ then if $A,B$ hold the balls, the distance is $1$.  If $A,C$ hold them, the distance is $2$.  If $A,D$ hold them the distance is again $2$ since the path $A-E-D$ has length $2$ (not counting the start).  Similarly, if $A,E$ hold them, the distance is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Because of being in a circle, the maximum distance between the two balls can only be $2$ (call it $d_2,\; say)$, and as Lulu has indicated, there are just two active states.

From the starting point $d_1$, with one step, with $Pr = \frac12$ each we either nove to $d_2$ or reach our goal, $d_0$, which can be written as

$d_1 = 0.5(1+d_2) + 0.5*1 (reached\; d_0)\tag 1$

From $d_1$, with one step we can only move to $d_2$, thus

$d_2 = 1+d_1 \tag 2$

Solving, we get $d_1=3$

Comment: You say that from $d_1$ we get to either $d_2$ or reach the goal but I dont think so. I think that either you go to $d_2$ either u stay $d_1$ as you swap places, no ?

Comment: @Atmos: If we just swap places, then we shall remain forever at $d_1\;$ ! The question makes sense only if one of them can move at a time.

Comment: So suppose your friend is at A, you are at B (thus distance $d_1$) and you move, you can either move to C or merge at A

Comment: Why only $d_1$ ? You only stay $d_1$if both balls are passed on in the same direction, if not you are not $d_1$ anymore

Comment: "Each turn, **A** person gives the ball to one of its neighbour (caps mine). Forget about persons, there are $2$ balls at $A$ and $B$ and **A** random ball moves randomly by one step either way. The distances we are counting, remember, is the distance *between* the two balls which can range between $0$ and $2$. I hope it is sufficiently clear now.

Comment: The problem statement is ambiguous.  Personally, I read it as requiring that *both* active players hand their ball to a neighbor (so, as the OP says) the probability that state $1$ stays in state $1$ is $\frac 34$, with a $\frac 14$ chance of moving to state $2$.  But, then, it does say that "each turn, a person gives the ball..." so the other reading makes sense too.

Comment: @lulu: For your interpretation, the proper wording would be "each turn, *each* person gives the ball..." Anyway, vague wordings are a nuisance, for sure.

Comment: Sorry but the initial formulation, translated from French, does not detail either. But the solution is given to be $8$

Answer (score 1):

I believe the interpretation that the original poster wants is:

"Two consecutive person hold in their hand a ball. Each turn, $\textit{each}$ person gives the ball to one of their neighbours. How many turns should you wait so that one person holds the two balls at the same time?"

To answer this question, consider the following. There are three states: $d_0$, $d_1$, and $d_2$, where $d_0$ is an absorbing state and $d_1,d_2$ are active states. The probability of transfer between any of these states can be described with the following $3\times3$ matrix $P$, indexed by $d_1,d_2,d_0$:
$$ P :=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This is an absorbing Markov Chain written in [$\textit{canonical form}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Canonical_form), and so it can be shown that the expected number of steps needed to be absorbed (i.e. reach $d_0$) can be calculated with the introduction of a new matrix we'll denote $N$, defined as:
$$
N = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4}\\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}^k= \left(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4}\\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}8 & 4\\
4 & 4 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
$N_{i,j}$ counts the expected number of visits to an active state $j$ starting from an active state $i$ before getting absorbed. Thus, to calculate how many rounds it should take in total before getting absorbed, we can consider the first entry of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}8 & 4\\
4 & 4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}12 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix}
$$
to see that 12 is the expected number of rounds needed for one person to hold both balls if the circle starts with adjacent members holding a ball.